# my Bootstrap model can not display correct angular Project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-modal

in my Project i use sideNav with router and different components when i navigate between 4 components and when i click button which diplay a model with this methode :

```
public onOpenModal(profile: Profile, mode: String) {
    console.log("openModel");
    const container = document.getElementById('main-container-edit');
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.style.display = 'none';
    button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
    if (mode === 'edit') {
      this.profile = profile;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#editProfileModal');
    }
    if (mode === 'delete') {
      this.deleteProfile = profile;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#deleteProfileModal');
    }
    container?.appendChild(button);
    button.click();

  }
```

this is the result: int tow photos
[the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCZhi.png) 
[model 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA1CW.png) 
donc i cant Access to It .

Comment: Not sure what exactly you’re trying to do here, however, this direct dom manipulation doesn’t look like the way to go. Why not use something like ngx-bootstrap that has a proper Angular based modal (and much more)?

Comment: thanks  it work for me

Comment: i change to ngx-bootstrap